# How to enable Rendering a 3D Surface Graphic on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, webgl

I have a 3D plot based on "https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-surface-plots/".
I implemented on Chrome but It show like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCOm4.png)
I want to rendering the graphic as a surface like plotly. I am currently using Chrome and GPU report is in belows.

*Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Canvas out-of-process rasterization: Disabled
Direct Rendering Display Compositor: Disabled
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated on all pages
Raw Draw: Disabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated
WebGPU: Hardware accelerated
Driver Bug Workarounds
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
disable_accelerated_av1_encode
disable_vp_scaling
disable_vp_super_resolution
enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
exit_on_context_lost
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
Problems Detected
Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Decode and Encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on Windows: 634519
Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
Expose WebGL's disjoint_timer_query extensions on platforms with site isolation: 808744, 870491
Applied Workarounds: enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
Don't use video processor scaling on non-Intel, non-NVIDIA GPUs.: 993233
Applied Workarounds: disable_vp_scaling
Don't use video processor super resolution on Intel Gen9 and older GPUs and non-Intel GPUs.: 1318380
Applied Workarounds: disable_vp_super_resolution
Disable hardware MFT Av1 encoder on machines with multiple GPUs: 1367038
Applied Workarounds: disable_accelerated_av1_encode*

I am also using D3D11 graphic backend. On chrome:flags I disabled #ignore-gpu-blocklist.

I dont know much about rendering or Chrome features but could you help me about what should I do next?

Rendering as 3D surface on Chrome